# Why are my HTML elements moving around depending on screen size or zoom?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, browser

My HTML and CSS elements are moving around depending on the screen size or zoom of a page. I have screenshots of this example.

[This is what it ends up looking like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSPhm.png)

[What it SHOULD look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OA266.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your HTML and CSS elements change with the screen size you can either write media queries or try putting your CSS in terms of percentages rather than pixels. For instance given this CSS code:

```
.some-class {
    width: 300px;
    padding: 25px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

All of those measurements in px are going to look very different on a phone screen vs a laptop screen because 300px is about 1/2 the width of a phone screen but only about 30% of a laptop screen. Rather than specify width in px, we can say we want some-class to take up a certain percentage of the screen like this:

```
.some-class{
    width: 30%;
}
```

Or like this:

```
.some-class{
    width: 30vw;
}
```

For the padding and margin we can write a media query, which changes the CSS according to screen size. Assuming our original code is for a laptop and we want to make it fit on a phone screen we can add the following to our CSS stylesheet:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px;){
    .some-class {
        padding: 15px;
        margin-top: 5px;
    }
}
```

This overwrites the original CSS if it detects a screen smaller than 480px across. It's worth knowing how to write media queries anyway in case something that is horizontally aligned on a laptop should be vertically aligned on a phone so here's a helpful link.

https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how I can keep the same size but convert my px measurements to viewport width?

Comment: What exactly do you want to keep the same size? Px is good for standardizing sizes. VW is generally used when you want something to take up a given portion of the screen, no matter what the size is. I suppose you could look up the widths of various devices and write media queries for each one in vw but that would be tedious. A possible alternative would be flex-shrink or flex-grow. Flexbox is something every frontend developer should know anyway IMO. Here's the link:https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I want the amount of space taken up on my screen that is currently represented in px to be the same size but in VW

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you want to keep the same size? Images? Text containers? Some code would help.